# Magento 2 social share buttons?

Tags: magento2, social-buttons, social

How to add Magento 2 social sharing links to the product view page? Actually, I have registered in `add this tool` and followed the steps to integrate `social sharing` via `AddThis snippet` I have a snippet that wants to place on the view page from the customer theme

Comment: On which section you want to place?

Comment: Hi @nagaraju did you added gmail share button here.

Comment: No @shivashankarm

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this,

Add this code in catalog_product_view.xml,

```
<referenceContainer name="product.info.social">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.socialmedia" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/socialmedia.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

And Create new phtml file at following path,

> app/design/frontend/Custom/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/socialmedia.phtml

Add below code in it.

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="social-media-icons">
    <!-- WhatsApp -->
    <a target="_blank" href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl());?>">
            WhatsApp</a>
    <!-- Facebook -->
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl());?>&t=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName())?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on facebook">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/facebook-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Facebook" width="12%">
    </a>
    <!-- TWITTER -->
    <a href="http://twitter.com/home/?status=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl());?>(<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName())?>)" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on Twitter">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/tw.png'); ?>" alt="Twitter" width="5%">
    </a>
    <!-- Pinterest -->
    <a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl()); ?>&media=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getImageUrl());?> &description=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getName()); ?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Pin it">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/pinterest-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Pinterest" width="12%">
    </a>
    <!-- Google Plus -->
    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($_product->getProductUrl()); ?>" onclick='javascript:window.open(this.href,"","width=640,height=480,left=0,top=0,location=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");return false' title="Share on Google Plus">
        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/google-plus-share.jpg'); ?>" alt="Google Plus" width="12%">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @kazim noorani where i need to keep this code ?

Comment: thats means calling how to do the calling

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check and let me know if you still need any help. @NagarajuKasa

Comment: hi @kazim one small doubt i  have added social sharing from addthis tool https://prnt.sc/jiwopy  https://prnt.sc/jiwp0o but unable to add instagram is it possible?

Comment: Aaamm, as far as I know, Instagram doesn't allow to upload images through their API. Still need to search for that. @NagarajuKasa

Comment: How to add instagram share and mailto from here?

Comment: how to perform any action after sharing the post? for example i want to update data in the db after the share on fb

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but here you go,

I don't want to use 3rd Party modules so i used FB JS to make it work.

> For FB

```
<div class="facebook_button social-button">
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.11';
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-layout="button" data-width="400" data-show-faces="false"  data-href="<?php echo $YourProductUrl; ?>"  data-send="true"></div></div>
```

> For Twitter

```
<div class='twitter_button social-button'>
    <a href='https://twitter.com/share' class='twitter-share-button' data-url="<?php echo $this->getProductUrl(); ?>" >Tweet</a>
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script></div>
```

This is working for me.

Comment: how to add instagram button?

Comment: Hi @user67337 How to add gmail share button here

Comment: Hi @nagaragu, i have added a facebook link, it is sharing but  how can i get the shared response id magento2

Comment: @jafarpinjar, I guess you cannot share  web urls to instagram