# Magento 2.3.4: Facebook error: the parameter app_id is required

Tags: magento2.3, api, facebook, app

clicking on the `facebook` symbol right below the `ADD TO CART` button returns the error `the parameter app_id is required` as seen in the screenshot below. Is there anything that should have been done before users can be allowed to use the `facebook` to promote the product from our Magento site?

[image]

Comment: are you using any extension for this ?

Comment: No, I don't think my site has a separate extension for this. Do I need an extension?

Comment: Not needed so what you have coded for sharing button ?

Comment: It is by default present on the product details page.

Comment: ok here in your code you need to mention app id..So if its readymade theme than you need to find this button code and need to pass app id of facebook..You have app_id ?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Share option also returns an error now `INCORRECT AUTHENTICATION DATA` . I will follow your instruction to pass the app id for the facebook.

Comment: this is is a problem of passing invalid data

Comment: Let me try to fix the facebook one first before share option.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226323/magento-2-social-share-buttons - please refer this code.

Comment: check if your facebook app detail you are passing is correct or not ?

Comment: Sure, I will look at at all these.

Comment: let me know if you need any more help ?

Comment: Sure, will let you know, thanks for your time and efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can refer this link

[Magento 2 social share buttons?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226323/magento-2-social-share-buttons)

But I would suggest check if all data you are passing to facebook request is proper or not

Comment: This was way too simpler than I thought. Just needed to create an App ID to be entered in the Magento Admin in the relelvant field for the custom theme that we are using besides some simple setup on the facebook developers page. Thanks

Comment: This is the best article that helped solve my problem. https://magenest.com/en/how-to-configure-facebook-api-in-magento-2/